# How to mix variable and string in js setAttribute() attribute value?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, setattribute

This is a basic question, but I somehow can't find the answer.

I would like to pass a mix of string and variable as the value for an attribute, in the setAttribute() method.

This is what I have:

```
    document.getElementById('mydiv').setAttribute("style", "width: 10%")
```

Instead of "width: 10%" I would like to have something like: "width: --myVar-- %"

All questions I find are related to passing only a variable but not how to mix both variable and string.

Thanx for any help!

Comment: You need to concatenate your string with your variable.

Comment: Try this: var foo = 20; document.getElementById('mydiv').setAttribute('style', 'width: '+ foo +'px');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way.

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').setAttribute("style", "width:"+ myVar+ "%")
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even be using setAttribute when there's a direct property and accessors:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.width = myVar + '%';
```